# testcafe execution via intelliJ run action

Tags: node.js, testing, intellij-idea, jestjs, testcafe

I have my testcafe test which is running well via terminal with

```
testcafe chrome jira-web-front\src\test\script\testcafe
```

I would like to be able to run it inside intelliJ js editor by clicking on the play button:
[image]

When I execute my test by clicking on the green play button I have:
[image]

I have some jest tests also in my project.
I tried to install intelliJ testcafe plugin but it didn't help.
Any idea about this?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The logic currently used by JavaScript support plugin for detecting what test runner is available for a given test file is based on dependencies declarations in `package.json` nearest to this file: it looks for known test runners listed there and tries to run the most suitable one. As IDEA
doesn't provide any support for *TestCafe* (https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-30315), you can't expect it to run TestCafe from a gutter; it runs your tests with *jest* because you have it in your dependencies list.

To run test using the run configuration provided by [testcafe plugin](https://github.com/lilbaek/webstorm-testcafe), you need right-clicking the test in editor:

[image]

This plugin doesn't support running tests from gutter, neither it supports debugging.

Note that you can use [VS Code recipes](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/recipes/debug-tests/visual-studio-code.html) to debug TestCafe in IDEA. Namely, you need **Node.js** Run configuration like the following:

[image]

where **JavaScript file:** is set to a path to your locally installed testcafe module, e.g. `node_modules\testcafe\bin\testcafe.js`, and **Application parameters:** are testcafe cli args, like 
`chrome myTestFile.js`